# GXT: How enable paginator?

Tags: java, pagination, gxt

I have working proxy:

```
    proxy = new RpcProxy<List<EmpDTO>>() {
        @Override
        protected void load(Object loadConfig,
                final AsyncCallback<List<EmpDTO>> callback) {
            EmpDTO empDTO = new EmpDTO();
            empService.findByExample(empDTO,
                    new AsyncCallback<List<EmpDTO>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                            callback.onFailure(ex);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<EmpDTO> result) {
                            callback.onSuccess(result);
                        }
                    });
        }

    };

    BeanModelReader reader = new BeanModelReader();

    loader = new BaseListLoader(proxy, reader);
    store = new ListStore(loader);
```

How to integrate pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that should answer your question,

http://www.sencha.com/examples/explorer.html#paging

Click the "source" tab at the bottom.